# Forcing PDFs to open in Browsers and not prompt to download

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, httpresponse

I have an application which displays PDFs I want to ensure that regardless of the device or browser that PDFs will be displayed in the browser and NOT downloaded.

Currently in a desktop browser the PDFs are being displayed in a browser and same on an IPhone but on an Android device theyre automatically downloading.

Is there any way to force this using HTTP Response Headers. I am using IIS7.

Comment: You can't really stop them. Even if you embed it, their browser's PDF handler can offer to print or save it.

Comment: @codran thanks for this - i have been using URL.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1 to try and restrict the options, even though someone would be able to screenshot etc, I want to try and prevent the glaringly obvious buttons being available, but restrict the documents from being accessed without the user authenticating themselves against the application first. But have consistency across accessing with SmartPhones, PCs and tablets. Android seems to download, so that's why I have been looking at the Google Docs embed.

Comment: Is there away to create a hidden folder which I can store the PDFs in so that my application can access the documents but a user couldnt use a FQDN to access them?

Comment: How can you, as the owner of a website, force browsers to do *your* bidding rather than the bidding of the owners of the devices on which the browsers are running? Do you not see that there would, maybe, be potential for misuse if such control was available to the world at large?